# Dropdown Selected Item Not Properly set

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where The Dropdownbox (selUsers) is populated from a database on pageload.

On LoadComplete I am setting the value based on a value from the maser page.

```
selUsers.SelectedValue = master.intUserID
```

This appears to work properly, as the correct text is displayed in the dropdownbox.

I have a button that calls a sub.  In that sub, hen I call selUsers.SelectedItem.Value or selUsers.SelectedValue I get the value of the first item in the dropdownbox not the selected one.

I have been reading and I am seeing that the code to set the value has to be in ispostback, but I am not posting the page back, nor do I want to.  Is it truly the case that even if you set the value of the dropdown, it isn't really set until you post the page back?  If that isnt the case, why am I not getting the correct value.

Before you ask, I have scoured the code, and at no place else is the dropdown being rebound, or the value being reset.

Answer (score 0):

the whole page life cycle can be a tad confusing.

I'd advise you to read this (article: ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

But to answer your question:

If you click that button , the following takes place in this specific order (relevant to your problem):

1) Page load event gets raised: this is where you get your data and databind, thus 'resetting' the selected value on the dropdownlist as well.

2) The button click event gets raised (this is an item event): You read out the value you want to read out
BUT since you haven't reached LoadComplete yet (where you'll set the new selected  value) you'll see the first value in the list.

3) Load complete event gets raised: here you set the correct selected value.

So yes, if you click on an asp web form's button (by default), it will cause a postback and go through the whole page life cycle to build the 'response' to your action. You'll have to take this into account while building your pages.

You can see this in action while debugging: place breakpoints on those 3 points in your code behind file and then click the button.

To solve your problem, you'll need to set the selected value after you databind your dropdownlist AND before you read out the selected value.

Hope this helps.